# Casting array of objects to array of subclassed objects in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have an array of EKReminder, like so:

```
var currentReminders: [EKReminder]? = ....
```

I want to cast this array to an array of subclasses of EKReminder. Let's say this is the subclass:

```
import Foundation
import EventKit

class NNReminder: EKReminder {
    var additionalNotes: String?
}
```

How would I cast currentReminders to [NNReminder]? I tried several ways but they all failed.

Comment: When you tried, what was the error message you received ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you are *sure* that all members of `currentReminders` are, in fact, `NNReminder`s, you can cast them all like this:

```
currentReminders = currentReminders.map { $0 as! NNReminder }
```

Edit: if only some of the reminders are of type `NNReminder`, or you're not sure of the array's contents, you can use `flatMap` to remove the nil values:

```
currentReminders = currentReminders.flatMap { $0 as? NNReminder }
```

If you are asking how to transform a bunch of objects that were initialized as `EKReminder`, you should write a custom `init` in `NNReminder` that takes an `EKReminder`, and use this `init` in the above map method.

Comment: Note that forced casts should be avoided as they tend to generate crashe

Comment: @Cristik yep, which is why I mentioned he should be sure the cast can be done (ie. he initialized the array himself with `NNReminder`s earlier). Edited in a safer operation though.

Comment: Thanks Connor! That helped. :)

Comment: This is for down-cast Array's. If you want to up-cast then you can just use as! [ClassTypeHere]

Answer (score 0):

**I was tired of having cryptic .map clauses all over my code so i wrote a small extension to make things neat:**

```
extension Array{
    func cast<T>(type:T.Type? = nil) -> [T]{
        return self.map { $0 as! T }
    }
}
```

**Example:**

```
class A:B{
    var value:String = "default"
    init(_ value:String){
        self.value = value
    }
}
class B{
    var someNum:CGFloat = 1
    init(){

    }
}
var arr1:Array<A> = [A("a"),A("b"),A("c")]
let arr2:Array<B> = arr1.cast(B.self)//neat!
let arr3:Array<B> = arr1.cast()//epic!
```

**NOTE:**
the cast method supports protocols as well

Comment: You can also make the parameter to the cast function optional with a default value of `nil` and it will infer the correct type so you don't have to pass `B.self`

Comment: Makes it even nicer! Nice catch "dan". Works flawlessly in playground, even tested it with a protocol just to be sure. I updated the code-example to reflect your suggestion.